# Nodejs App crashes when deploying on Heroku. Works locally

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, deployment

I have now spent a couple of days searching for reasons why this is happening and have tried to make sure all file names are consistent both locally and in the git push since I hear that Heroku can be funny about this.

The app works absolutely fine on my local server I should add.

Here is the heroku logs coming from when I restart the app on heroku:

```
2019-03-04T21:42:46.527650+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-03-04T21:42:49.314540+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921757+00:00 app[web.1]: { NODE_HOME: '/app/.heroku/node',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921775+00:00 app[web.1]: NODE_ENV: 'production',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921776+00:00 app[web.1]: WEB_MEMORY: '512',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921777+00:00 app[web.1]: DYNO: 'web.1',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921779+00:00 app[web.1]: PWD: '/app',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921780+00:00 app[web.1]: HOME: '/app',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921781+00:00 app[web.1]: PORT: '51817',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921782+00:00 app[web.1]: MEMORY_AVAILABLE: '512',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921783+00:00 app[web.1]: WEB_CONCURRENCY: '1',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921784+00:00 app[web.1]: SHLVL: '1',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921785+00:00 app[web.1]: PATH:
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921787+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/.heroku/node/bin:/app/.heroku/yarn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/app/bin:/app/node_modules/.bin',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921788+00:00 app[web.1]: PS1:
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921790+00:00 app[web.1]: '\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\] \\[\\033[01;32m\\]$ \\[\\033[00m\\]',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921791+00:00 app[web.1]: _: '/app/.heroku/node/bin/node',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921792+00:00 app[web.1]: COUDINARY_NAME: 'djbcg1deo',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921793+00:00 app[web.1]: COUDINARY_API_KEY: '571183338823141',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921794+00:00 app[web.1]: COUDINARY_API_SECRET: 'DkJ_3UsH7DLTsHHwmD68AMUYJzY',
2019-03-04T21:42:50.921795+00:00 app[web.1]: DB_URI: 'node-js-blog' }
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723033+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723058+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723060+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723061+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723063+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './controllers/createPost'
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723066+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723068+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723069+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723071+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723073+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:14:30)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723074+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723076+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723078+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723079+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723081+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723082+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723084+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.723086+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
2019-03-04T21:42:51.789482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-03-04T21:42:51.770169+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-03-04T21:43:12.736446+00:00 heroku[run.9030]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2019-03-04T21:43:13.319723+00:00 heroku[run.9030]: State changed from up to complete
2019-03-04T21:43:13.297680+00:00 heroku[run.9030]: Process exited with status 129
2019-03-04T21:43:16.063306+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=james-node-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=b16a486a-239e-4bc4-9673-4f24febd9265 fwd="82.6.200.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-04T21:43:17.018561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=james-node-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=63cc1508-3943-4251-b424-674186d84e76 fwd="82.6.200.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Also, the code can be found on my Github repo here:

https://github.com/jameslevine/Nodejs-Blog

I would greatly appreciate some pointers if anyone has any since I am going round in circles at this point.

Thanks in advance!

Update: Resolved 2 errors. First one was the filename change and the second was the fact that .gitignore didn't include the node_modules file. Now app gives this log, which indicates it is no longer crashing. However, I still can't see the app by clicking on Live App on Heroku. Any help there?

I have included logs below:

```
2019-03-05T08:59:41.441061+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2019-03-05T08:59:41.444978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-03-05T08:59:42.400893+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-03-05T08:59:42.520869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-03-05T08:59:43.970483+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929838+00:00 app[web.1]: { NODE_HOME: '/app/.heroku/node',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929860+00:00 app[web.1]: NODE_ENV: 'production',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929862+00:00 app[web.1]: WEB_MEMORY: '512',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929863+00:00 app[web.1]: DYNO: 'web.1',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929865+00:00 app[web.1]: PWD: '/app',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929867+00:00 app[web.1]: HOME: '/app',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929868+00:00 app[web.1]: PORT: '54093',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929869+00:00 app[web.1]: MEMORY_AVAILABLE: '512',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929870+00:00 app[web.1]: WEB_CONCURRENCY: '1',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929871+00:00 app[web.1]: SHLVL: '1',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929873+00:00 app[web.1]: PATH:
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929874+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/.heroku/node/bin:/app/.heroku/yarn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/app/bin:/app/node_modules/.bin',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929875+00:00 app[web.1]: PS1:
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929877+00:00 app[web.1]: '\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\] \\[\\033[01;32m\\]$ \\[\\033[00m\\]',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929878+00:00 app[web.1]: _: '/app/.heroku/node/bin/node',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929879+00:00 app[web.1]: COUDINARY_NAME: 'djbcg1deo',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929880+00:00 app[web.1]: COUDINARY_API_KEY: '571183338823141',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929881+00:00 app[web.1]: COUDINARY_API_SECRET: 'DkJ_3UsH7DLTsHHwmD68AMUYJzY',
2019-03-05T08:59:45.929882+00:00 app[web.1]: DB_URI: 'node-js-blog' }
2019-03-05T08:59:46.787139+00:00 app[web.1]: Tue, 05 Mar 2019 08:59:46 GMT express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option at index.js:38:9
2019-03-05T08:59:46.787355+00:00 app[web.1]: Tue, 05 Mar 2019 08:59:46 GMT express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option at index.js:38:9
2019-03-05T08:59:46.795789+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
2019-03-05T08:59:46.796700+00:00 app[web.1]: App listing on port 54093
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804363+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804367+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804369+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804370+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804372+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804373+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804375+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804377+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804378+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804380+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804382+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804384+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804474+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
2019-03-05T08:59:46.804552+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2019-03-05T08:59:47.581487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-03-05T09:00:21.698023+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=james-node-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=55c8cc21-6544-4e4c-800f-62eac6ed8034 fwd="62.30.226.42" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2019-03-05T09:01:18.887286+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H15 desc="Idle connection" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=james-node-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=ccfeba5b-3105-423c-87f6-edfe9ba86584 fwd="62.30.226.42" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=55036ms status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Any ideas why it is now not showing live? I am just beginning to research this and think it is something to do with the server not starting but thought I would update on progress as I go along.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a typo, you're trying to require `createPost` in index.js:14 and the file is actually called `createpost.js`

`Error: Cannot find module './controllers/createPost'`

It's weird, though, that it's working locally.

Comment: Okay, it's actually not, some files systems are case-insensitive.

Comment: Right, if OP is developing on Windows (for example) those filenames would be interchangeable. Heroku, like all sane platforms, treats them differently.

Comment: Thanks very much! Errors resolved! There was actually another one which was resolved by adding in the node_modules to .gitignore. Now onto figuring out why the app isn't showing live on heroku. Any advice? I'm sure I'm missing a step somewhere and as you have probably guessed, this is my first time deploying on Heroku.